# Rewrite PNG URL to PHP File

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please forgive me, but I'm VERY new to PHP, and even worse with url rewrites.

I'd like to write a PHP script that will dynamically output an image that will then be used as a signature on a forum that I belong to.

I have a base PHP file that I'm working with and will be editing that so I'm able to host it for other users of this forum.

The information will be stored in a database, and I'd like to call the PHP script with a PNG URL

Example:

```
http://somedomain.com/somecode.png
```

rewriting that to

```
http://somedomain.com/sig_img.php?img=somecode
```

Where `somecode` is the database table primary index.

I don't really need help with the PHP script (yet), but I have no clue where to begin with the `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` code.

Thank you all for any assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that mod_rewrite is enabled, something like this should work:

```
<Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    # ensure requested resource is not a file.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    # ensure requested resource is not a directory.
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*\.png)$ sig_img.php?img=$1 [NC,L]
</Location>
```

This will redirect any request that is a not a file or directory to the script `sig_img.php` with the requested filename as the parameter.  You may want to restrict this to only .PNG file requests, in which case please [read about the options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Make sure you treat the request as untrusted and parameterise the input; don't just concatenate `$_GET['img']` into your query string.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and apologize for my uninformed initial post.  I will certainly treat it as untrusted and will clean any input given, especially given that I'll be using this with a database.

I will do more research in the future before posing a question here.

Comment: No need to apologise; your question is fine (but could be readily solved with a bit of reading and testing). As you mentioned querying a database with the input value I instinctively added the last sentence. I simply wanted to warn you about the risk in case you weren't aware.